Can't access Docker Tomcat App runing in Elastic Beanstalk
I've have a Red Hat Enterprise Docker container where I install Tomcat and am running a custom Tomcat application. I wish to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. The application works as expected when I run it locally with Docker on my workstation at the IP: http://localhost:8080/ephemeral.server/login.jsp?goto=/ephemeral.server/html/next/index.jsp.
However; when I deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk, I cannot get it to work. The public domain provided times out and I cannot figure out why. I have tried to access both on port 8080 and port 80. For example, I take the Domain created for the environment and try to access my site. First tried 8080:
http://<beanstalk-app>.eba-8ebiumxm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:8080/ephemeral.server/login.jsp?goto=/ephemeral.server/html/next/index.jsp 

Then I try on port 80:
http://<beanstalk-app>.eba-8ebiumxm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ephemeral.server/login.jsp?goto=/ephemeral.server/html/next/index.jsp 

Response is always:
"This site can’t be reached....refused to connect.
Try: Checking the connection"
Step 1: Build the Container (Docker run, Docker build):
FROM  --platform=linux/amd64 registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi:latest

# Install necessary packages 
RUN dnf update -y && \
    dnf install -y tar gzip unzip

# Add the JRE
COPY jre-8u411-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt/

# COPY and overwrite the catalina.properties
COPY catalina.properties /opt/

# Copy Server installer.
COPY Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux.zip /opt

# Add the server.xml
ADD server.xml /opt

# Add Tomcat
COPY apache-tomcat-9.0.91.tar.gz /opt/


# Unzip the Installer.
RUN unzip /opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux.zip -d /opt

# Give run permissions to install script.
RUN chmod +x /opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux/install.sh

# Make an jre directory in opt and extract the contents
RUN mkdir -p /opt/jre && tar -xvf /opt/jre-8u411-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jre --strip-components=1

# Set JAVA_HOME and PATH
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jre
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Extract Tomcat
RUN tar -xvf /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.91.tar.gz -C /opt

# Rename Tomcat
RUN mv /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.91 /opt/tomcat

# Overwrite the server.xml with the connector properties. 
RUN mv /opt/server.xml /opt/tomcat/conf/

# Overwrite the catalina.properties with custom properties. 
RUN mv /opt/catalina.properties /opt/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties

# Remove the old tomcat directory.
RUN rm /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.91.tar.gz

# Create tomcat group and user
RUN groupadd tomcat \
  && useradd -M -s /sbin/nologin -g tomcat tomcat

# Change ownership of the Tomcat directory
RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat

RUN ls -l /opt/tomcat/lib/

# Set environment variables
ENV CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
ENV CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
ENV CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"
ENV evolven_server_root=/opt/tomcat
ENV EVOLVEN_SERVER_ROOT=/opt/tomcat

# Expose Tomcat port
EXPOSE 8080

# RUN mv /opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux/lib/*.jar /opt/tomcat/lib/ 


# Install it!
# RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /etc/environment && ./opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux/install.sh -t /opt/tomcat -d $DB_HOST -p 5432 -u $DB_USER -P $DB_PASSWORD -c $DB_NAME'
RUN ./opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux/install.sh -t /opt/tomcat -d someurl.rds.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -u postgres -P <omitted> -c postgres

# RUN rm -rf /opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux/

# Remove the Evolven Server Installer.
RUN rm /opt/Server.Installer.7.7.2.4484_linux.zip

# Remove the JRE
RUN rm /opt/jre-8u411-linux-x64.tar.gz

# Run Tomcat
# ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
# CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
# CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
USER tomcat

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out"]

Step 2: Created a Dockerrun.aws.json file referencing my Docker app like this:
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "myrepo/tomcat-image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}

Step 3: Then I run: "eb init", "eb create my-tomcat-env", "eb deploy".
I looked at the security group and attached to the EC2 instance hosting my Beanstalk instance and opened an inbound port on 8080.

What else can I do to debug this?

Was able to get it working first thing that was the issue was adding a port mappings, and sizing.

Port Mappings: Mapped the containerPort to port 80.
Sizing: Changed the profile to m5.2xlarge from t3.micro (my app requires A LOT more memory than a t3.micro instance).

Here's my updated Dockerrun.aws.json.
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "bronette/tomcat-app",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "containerPort": 8080
        }
    ],
    "Volumes": [],
    "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
} 

